# How to configure Linux Mint in order to file manager sort filenames using different algorithms?

Tags: sort, file-manager

I'm not being able to sort files the way I want with my file manager on Linux Mint and I would like to know if there's any hidden config to change that.

For example, I'm sorting: 
"a.txt", "(b).txt", "c.txt" >> It shows a symbol in the middle of the list.

For some reason the sorting done is like that instead of the desired:
"(b).txt, "a.txt", "c.txt" >> I want the symbols at the beginning.

How do I tweak my file manager or my Linux to sort files the way I like/want/need? Could it be done through dconf-editor?

Comment: It's a (mis)feature of locale settings.  The "fix" would be to use POSIX locale, but at the cost of losing Unicode...

Comment: Dolphin file manager sorts the three files like this: `(b).txt` first, `a.txt` second, and `c.txt` third. I didn't mess with locale settings.

Comment: What file manager are you using?

Comment: It's true, Dolphin works that way, but I don't know how to make it use a dark theme. I think I'm going to give it a try to create a new locale.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by creating your own locale and tweaking it until it becomes exactly like you want it to be, **but it's going to be a lot of work!**  *Possible: yes, practical: no.*
Having said that, it involves the following steps and as you're using Linux Mint, you should follow the Ubuntu rules:

1. Choose the name of the locale in the format of `LL_RR@MM`, where `LL` is the language, `RR` is the region and `MM` is a modifier that you *probably* won't need (unless you want it to include non-western characters like Cyrillic or Greek or worse  **;-)**.)
2. Create a file with that name. (or copy an existing one, depending on your needs)
3. Define the locale.
   *This is where the **lots of work** comes in.*  You should pay special attention to the collating sequence.
4. Deploy the locale: Once your locale file or files are ready, you should test them locally to ensure they are correct. The basic steps are:

   - copying the file to `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`
   - Generating a binary file to be used by applications

     ```
     localedef -i inputfile -c -f <charset> <locale>
     ```

For more information, see the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/KnowledgeBase/AddingNewLanguage) except the bit where it tells you to **6. Submit the locale to glibc**.  Thats not necessary in your case as you're not creating a new country / language.  **0:-)**