# How do I customize Nautilus / Caja file manager?

Tags: options, file-manager, development

I'm using Caja and I miss several features that I had with Windows Explorer.
I'm willing to tweak some configs or even develop code to get them but I wouldn't know where to start to collaborate... These are the features:

1. More columns: audio bit rate, image width and height, date created, exif data, audio length, ...
2. A property tab inside properties window for a file that shows file hashes SHA, MD5, CRC32, ...
3. Set icon sizes the same, on the treeview and on the listview
4. Create a set of actions available from file context menú to do with that file: get hash, get audio properties, get document hidden properties and such...
5. Inherit folder color. Despite a set a color to a folder, its subfolders don't inherit the parent color.
6. Delete or change position to "Link to..." when creating soft links from a file. Maybe "aFile.txt - Link" would be more practical...
7. Add more sizes to zoom in order to see files and folders on the right part. As far as I know there are only 5 positions.
8. Use "move/copy to" and remember the places like thunderbird does when moving/copying messages.
9. Always show tabs and a filterbox on the top right with an option for searching on subdirectories...
10. Use a vertical menu, instead of using a dropdown control on the left part of caja file manager for selecting places. I would upload a mockup for this one.
11. Sorting files like in Windows Explorer (already treated at [How to configure Linux Mint in order to file manager sort filenames using different algorithms?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491873/how-to-configure-linux-mint-in-order-to-file-manager-sort-filenames-using-differ))

I hope you can give me some tweaks or programming clues to get some or all of these features. Ah! Happy new year everyone!
(3)

Answer (score 0):

The "Link to " preappended text you describe in #6 has annoyed me for a long time, and your post finally motivated me to do something about it.

I put together a simple Perl script that can be run as a Caja Action from a button or menu selection within Caja to trim off that preappended text from all links in a directory. It's not exactly what you're looking for -- you have to manually run it on a directory after links are created -- but it's probably the best that can be done without digging to the Caja source code or implementing system-wide monitoring of file creation.

The script's up at https://gitlab.com/dyockey/trimlinkto. There's a lengthy manpage-like chunk of documentation at the top of the file that explains its use with Caja. Feel free to mod it to provide postappended text if you'd like.